# HTML audio tag on IPhone is hidden by the half of the height

Tags: ios, css, iphone, html, audio

When I add audio tag to html and try to see it on IPhone 5 it has only half the size. How do I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="controls" type="audio/mpeg">
            <source type="audio/mp3" src="someSource.mp3">
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I zoom in then it works. But not in the normal screen.

**Wrong:**[image]

**Expected:** [image]

If I add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

It would also show up properly but would become half height once zoomed out.

Also flipping screen horizontally makes it a little bit higher.

**EDIT screen after @Romain suggestion:**

[image]

Comment: why suggestion to close without comment?

Comment: I am having the same issue...

Comment: In case you are interested I ended up using some js library for audio instead of using native one

Answer (score 1):

You only need to expand your tag to full width of your container and adjust a minimum height that will suit all browsers

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="block"></div>
        <audio id="audio" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="controls" type="audio/mpeg">
            <source type="audio/mp3" src="someSource.mp3">
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    audio {
       width:100% !important;
       min-height: 30px;
       display:block;
    }


    #block {
           height:100px;
           width: 50px;
           background: blue;
        }
```

The issue is your audio tag is floating on the left (not big enough) and it is displayed under a web browser bar.
Here, I don't think the audio tag is the problem. Try to had another html element to review if the tag is well displayed.

Comment: The issue is not with the width but with the height. Making width 100% just changes the width, but the height is still half size. Setting height to 100px would make it appear but then it would break other browsers

Comment: I modified the title to be more specific

Comment: tried min-height: 30px it but it doesn't change. As with height, if I set it to higher value like 100px it works but it then ruins the style of other browsers.

Comment: I have modified to show how your changes  looks like on iphone5

Answer (score 0):

I also had to set height:100px; on audio to get full play arrow height to show.  It did move the control down in other browsers but I can live with a little white space above the control.  Add this to css or to head of the page:

```
<style>
    audio {height:100px;}
</style>
```